# Reach the parent element from the child

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have some elements that contain a couple of elements. I want when I click on the child element, the parent of the element disappears with all its nested elements (nested_parent and the nested_parent1 and the child) .

```css
.parent{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.nested_parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.nested_parent1 {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.child {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: beige;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
        <span class="nested_parent">
            <span class="nested_parent1">
                <i class="child"></i>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <span class="nested_parent">
            <span class="nested_parent1">
                <i class="child"></i>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <span class="nested_parent">
            <span class="nested_parent1">
                <i class="child"></i>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: And when you tried to write the code for that, where did you get stuck? What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a click handler to the children:

```
$('i.child').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().hide()
})
```

When you click a child, it will cause its grandparent to hide (`.nested_parent`), which automatically hides its descendants (`.nested_parent1` and `.child`).